# Return from loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, return

```
for (j in 1:2){ #first iteration
  for (i in 1:2){ #second iteration
    lst1 <- replicate(i,  data.frame( 
      matrix(c(letters[1:2], 
               sample(c(rep(1,100),0), size = 1),
               sample(c(rep(0,100),1), size = 1)),  ncol = 2) ), simplify = FALSE)
  }      
  return(lst1)
}
```

I would expect that `lst1` would return from second loop (i) to go to next iteration of the first loop (j).

I know I would do something like this `replicate(i*j,....)` to get all iterations but this solution doesn't meet my expectations.

output is list of 2

```
a, b 
0, 1
a, b
0, 1
```

but I would expect list of 4 (two iterations with two steps)

Comment: `return` can only be called from a `function`, not from a `for` (or other looping) structure. To capture the value returned by this, perhaps `lapply(1:2, function(i) lapply(1:2, function(i) { replicate(i, data.frame(...)); }))`?

Comment: Thank you for lapply suggestion. But with this I can't control output of iteration. It works more like replicate(i*j,....). I would like to subtract output and iterate again in my next code.

Comment: That makes no sense: just about anything you can do in a `for` loop can be done in an `lapply` call.

Comment: I think it would help solve your problem if you explain better *"this solution doesn't meet my expectations"* (regarding `replicate(i*j,...)`) and *"can't control output of iteration"*.

Answer (score 1):

`return()` is only meant to be used inside a function, not in a loop. Are you looking for the control flows `break` or `next`?

From the documentation in R:

> `break` breaks out of a for, while or repeat loop; control is transferred to the first statement outside the inner-most loop. `next` halts the processing of the current iteration and advances the looping index. Both break and next apply only to the innermost of nested loops.

Comment: Thank you for provide more information. I can't find much about return() in R help. But even if I used break() or next() I am not able to push lst1 to iterate it over again.

Comment: `break` and `next` are used without brackets (not `break()`).  Further, they don't return any values - they just transfer control within the loops. With loops in R one don't usually "push" an object to be iterated over again - you need some other way to append or add to your object. Maybe if you open another question focusing on what you want to achieve we could help you with some better alternatives.